# C++ pointer to std::string updated in function - scope issue? (ESP32)

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I have a

```
std::string
```

and pass that by reference to a function.

The function dereferences the parameter (pointer) into a local std::string for ease of working.

I update the local string's value and then update the pointer.

Have I just pointed to something that's gone out of scope? Or have I updated the underlying value of the string pointed to by string abc in the example below?

BTW It works but I'm concerned I'm breaking C++ rules.

```
int main() {
  
  std::string abc = R"(This is a string "raw" literal)";
  
  updateStringValue(&abc);

  log_v(abc.c_str());

}

void updateStringValue(std::string *theData) {

  std::string localString = (*theData);

  localString.append("some other value");

  *theData = localString;
}
```

I realise that the local string "localString" only survives the function but has the amended value really been retained (or maybe it's still floating around in memory but now out of scope once the function ends)?

I expected this to work (it did) but am having doubts.

Previously I did not dereference the incoming data's pointer into a local string but the resulting syntax was more confusing (to others) so I did it this way to simplify the overall structure.

I've definitely confused myself now.

Comment: *and pass that by reference to a function.* -- Your code does not pass the `std::string` by reference.  Passing a pointer is not passing by reference.  Passing a pointer is still pass-by-value.  Passing by reference would be `void updateStringValue(std::string &theData)`, and then `updateStringValue(abc);`

Comment: the code is safe and does what you expect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I realise now that I misspoke. How should I have described passing a pointer (specifically using the ampersand in front of the variable name, ie not by value). Is there a special term I should be using, or just "passed a pointer to the string"?

Comment: It is better to simply say "pass a pointer to the string".  In C++, "pass-by-reference" has a specific meaning.  In other languages, the term "reference" seems to be used in a non-formal manner, but not so for C++.

Comment: What you do is useless use of a pointer anyway. Don't use pointers unless you really have to (dynamic polymorphism), if you want to use pointers first check std::unique_ptr and when you pass raw pointers then they should be non-owning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine. `*theData = localString;` invokes copy assignment, so the caller's `string` is changed to be equivalent to (but not the same object as) `localData`. After that, `localData` gets cleaned when the function returns, but that's fine, the copy has already occurred.

To be clear, you did not pass by reference (that would be `void updateStringValue(std::string& theData)`, with an `&`, not a `*`, and no need for the caller to explicitly take the address of their local variable). Passing-by-reference would save you the need to manually dereference the pointer.

Also note, there's no need to make the copy here. You could just call:

```
theData->append("some other value");
```

or if you used a true reference:

```
theData.append("some other value");
```

and save the local copy and copy-back entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I only made the copy so that functions to update the local string were syntactically clearer but I think directly using the incoming parameter is just as clear (even for beginners who run screaming at the thought of a pointer) and are more efficient.